# Stopping or slowing a program from a script

Tags: python, debugging, synchronization, external

I have a program, which I want to synchronize to a script (currently Python). Right now the execution of the program is asynchronous to the script, which fetches the current states and is controlling its inputs. The program is deterministic, but throughout the execution it is coincidence if I fetch a few states earlier or later at a specific time (memory values). If I would be able to have more control over the program flow, the results would also be more deterministic and reproducible.

Is there even the slightest possibility to stop a program at a time point, make some actions and start it again, everything from an external script? A little bit like a debugger is able to stop a program during the execution and then resume it again.

Another way could be, if there was a possibility to at least slow down the program execution (even better to a specific speed). Like a "CPU Killer" which slows down the computer, but just for the program. In this case the script has more time to react in a (maybe even standard) bigger time slot.

The script wouldn't have to be Python either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use signals, this is how debuggers do it. For Python, the `signal` package provides utilities for handling signals.

Comment: Do you maybe have a good example/tutorial for this? I find a lot of examples how to use signals in python, but I don't understand the connection to external processes and how I would be able to interrupt them.

Comment: The first thing is to figure out which OS you're running this on. If a POSIX system then fine, signals work. Otherwise, you'll need to build out your own RPC, probably using `socket`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the time module to slow down the execution speed. I would use a boolean loop to check whether you should continue execution or not.

```
import time
while wait = False:
    if wait == False:
        run logic
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly you would slow down the python script to a constant rate instead of the program, with the hope of getting a more deterministic flow of the program states? I also thought about that. Nonetheless the other way round would be nicer...